# Randomly drop rows of subgroup on two conditions (crosstabulation)

Tags: r

I have a data frame, with the following columns: `date`, `outcome` (`no` or `yes`), and `group` (`one` or `two`):

```
set.seed(36)
Data <- data.frame(
date = sample((as.Date(as.Date("2011-12-30"):as.Date("2012-01-04"),
                       origin="1970-01-01")), 1000, replace = TRUE),
group = sample(c("one", "two"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
outcome = sample(c("no", "yes"), 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

I now crosstabulate by `group` and `outcome`, like so:

```
mytable <- table(Data$outcome, Data$group)
mytable
```

giving me a result like

```
      one two
  no  260 271
  yes 235 234
```

I would now like to randomly drop (or sample from - not sure which way is better; I believe they should have the same effect, although I'm not sure) rows from one of the cell columns, say the top-right corner (group `two` and outcome `no`) and keep 10% of the data.

Can someone point me into the right direction about which commands and conditions I would have to use?

Comment: Keep 10% from "two" and "no" group? i.e only 27 rows for that group? BTW, for me the results are interchanged for `one` and `two`.

Comment: Yes, 10% from `two`/`no` - the data frame I'm actually looking at is much larger, so don't mind the numbers too much. And not sure what's behind the interchanged order of groups...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this...

```
idx <- which(Data$group=="one" & Data$outcome=="no") #identify relevant group

Data2 <- Data[-sample(idx, 0.9*length(idx), replace=FALSE),] #sample 90% to remove

table(Data2$outcome, Data2$group)
      one two
  no   28 260
  yes 234 235

table(Data$outcome, Data$group)         
      one two
  no  271 260
  yes 234 235
```

Strangely I get the columns the other way round from you with that value of `set.seed`!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data2 <-
  Data %>%
  split(group_indices(.,group,outcome)) %>%
  purrr::modify_if(~first(.$group)=="two" & first(.$outcome)=="no",
                   ~slice(.,sample(nrow(.),round(nrow(.)/10)))) %>%
  bind_rows



table(Data2$outcome, Data2$group)
# one two
# no  271  26
# yes 234 235
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a function to make it more generalised :

```
get_reduced_data <- function(Data, group, outcome) {
   #Get indices of the subset which satisfies our condition
   indx = which(Data$group == group & Data$outcome == outcome)
   #Select only 10% from the subset and keep remaining rows as it is
   Data[c(sample(indx, length(indx) * 0.1), setdiff(seq(nrow(Data)), indx)), ]
}

df = get_reduced_data(Data, "two", "no")

table(df$outcome, df$group)

#      one two
#  no  271  26
#  yes 234 235

df = get_reduced_data(Data, "one", "no")

table(df$outcome, df$group)

#      one two
#  no   27 260
#  yes 234 235
```